# Infinite loop with target.address

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am creating a small program which will look for a change in column I on sheet "current". If a change is found, it will cut, and paste that whole column into the last row of the sheet "completed". It seems that when it does the cut, it gets stuck in a infinite loop causing it to never hit the message box "Made it.". How can I re-justify the address so that this issue can be avoided?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim LastRowCompleted As Long
    LastRowCompleted = Sheets("completed").Cells(Sheets("completed").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowCompleted = LastRowCompleted + 1 'Next row after last row

    Set KeyCells = Range("I:I")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        MsgBox Range(Target.Address).Row
        MsgBox Range(Target.Address).Column

        'Cut and Paste Row
        Range(Range(Target.Address).Row & ":" & Range(Target.Address).Row).Cut Sheets("completed").Range(LastRowCompleted & ":" & LastRowCompleted)
        MsgBox "Made it."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `Range(Range(Target.Address).Row & ":" & Range(Target.Address).Row).Cut` can be simply written `Target.EntireRow.Cut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Sheet Change event always disable the events if you are changing the cell content in the code otherwise the change event will be triggered repeatedly with each change on the sheet.

To disable the events use the following line in the beginning of the code

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And then don't forget to enable the event in the end otherwise any event code will not be triggered automatically.

To enable the events, use the following line before the End Sub.

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

So your code should be like this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim LastRowCompleted As Long
    LastRowCompleted = Sheets("completed").Cells(Sheets("completed").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowCompleted = LastRowCompleted + 1 'Next row after last row

    Set KeyCells = Range("I:I")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        MsgBox Range(Target.Address).Row
        MsgBox Range(Target.Address).Column

        'Cut and Paste Row
        Range(Range(Target.Address).Row & ":" & Range(Target.Address).Row).Cut Sheets("completed").Range(LastRowCompleted & ":" & LastRowCompleted)
        MsgBox "Made it."
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```